# How to stop iOS from compressing video when picked with Flutter image_picker?

Tags: flutter, video-capture, flutter-image-picker

Using Flutter and the `image_picker` package.

When selecting or recording a video on iOS the video is compressed before returning to the app. What I would like is the full, uncompressed video.

Furthermore, if a user locks their screen while the video is compressing the video is lost.

I can implement my own camera widgets and do the recording myself but I would rather not, and I would still be faced with compressed video when picked from the camera roll.

Comment: "What I would like is the full, uncompressed video." - what is "uncompressed" video for some `*.mp4` file?

Comment: Fair enough. What I mean is that I would like the video as it comes directly from the camera app (in whatever format it natively chooses) without the additional compression step that iOS seems to apply.

Comment: got any answer?

Comment: Nossir I did not.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to pick video, you can try out [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package. It seems like it does not compress. You can pick it with this code:

```
Future<String?> _selectVideo() async {
  FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.video,
    allowMultiple: false,
    allowCompression: false
  );
  return result?.paths.first;
}
```